# Sublime text auto close tags in JSP

Tags: jsp, tags, sublimetext3

In sublime text when you type `</` it automatically closes a open html tag for you. This is a awesome feature unfortunately the JSP syntax doesn't seem to recognise self closing tags so if I have

```
<p>
    <cms:pageSlot position="BodyImage" var="feature">
        <cms:component component="${feature}"/>
    </cms:pageSlot>
```

and I type `</` it completes to `</cms:component>` because it doesn't recognise the `<cms:component component="${feature}"/>` as a self closing tag and thinks that it is the last open tag.

How do I get it to close the `</p>` instead? It doesn't do this on `<img.../>` or `<input.../>` so there must be a way to get it to recognise some jsp tags as self closing.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming for the moment you know how to find and edit the file `Java Server Pages (JSP).tmLanguage` in the `Packages/Java` folder. If that's a bad assumption then please let me know and I'll expand the answer to cover that part.

Add the following to `Java Server Pages (JSP).tmLanguage` and I believe you will see the behaviour you are seeking. Seems to work for me. Please let me know if it does or doesn't work for you.

```
<dict>
  <key>begin</key>
  <string>(&lt;/?)((?i:com)\b)</string>
  <key>beginCaptures</key>
  <dict>
    <key>1</key>
    <dict>
      <key>name</key>
      <string>punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html.jsp</string>
    </dict>
    <key>2</key>
    <dict>
      <key>name</key>
      <string>entity.name.tag.inline.any.html.jsp</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
  <key>end</key>
  <string>((?: ?/)?&gt;)</string>
  <key>endCaptures</key>
  <dict>
    <key>1</key>
    <dict>
      <key>name</key>
      <string>punctuation.definition.tag.end.html.jsp</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>meta.tag.inline.any.html.jsp</string>
  <key>patterns</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>include</key>
      <string>#tag-stuff</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
</dict>
```